# Mapping to complex type (Entity Framework) giving error

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework database first approach. I am creating complex types for my stored procedure so that I can use it in my ASP.NET MVC application. I need to create the complex type as Entity Framework doesn't create it for me. I am unable to map the complex type with entity class that created. I am getting an error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'int'

Could somebody tell me what the problem is?

Stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spUserExists]
    (@NetworkID varchar(20),
     @Domain varchar(50),
     @RoleID int)
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount on

    ----------------------------------------
    -- variables
    ----------------------------------------

    -- error
    declare @ErrorMessage nvarchar(2048), @ErrorSeverity int, @ErrorState int

    ----------------------------------------
    -- exists
    ----------------------------------------

    declare @UserExists int; set @UserExists = 0

    begin try

        select @UserExists = 1
        where exists (Select up.NetworkID, up.Domain, ur.RoleId 
                      from dbo.UserProfile up 
                      inner join UserProfileRoleLink ur on up.UserProfileId = ur.UserProfileId
                      where up.NetworkID = @NetworkID 
                        and up.Domain = @Domain 
                        and ur.RoleId = @RoleID)

    end try
    begin catch
        select 
            @ErrorMessage = dbo.GetErrorMessage('Exists', error_message(), object_schema_name(@@procid), object_name(@@procid), error_line()), 
            @ErrorSeverity = error_severity(), 
            @ErrorState = error_state();

        raiserror(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);

        return
    end catch

    select @UserExists as UserExists
END
```

Entity class:

```
   public class ValidUser
    {
        public Int32 UserExists { get; set; }
    }
```

Function import:

[image]

Complex type:

[image]

Mapping and returning value:

```
public static System.Int32 UserValidate()
{
        using (var db = new MCREntities())
        {
            var isValid = db.spUserExists(GetShortname(), GetDomain(), 1);
            return Mapper.Map<List<ValidUser>>(isValid);
        }
}
```

Comment: could u describe `var isValid` what type is it? as the error message it is a List u should take a look at this.

Comment: Its a list i believe.

Comment: ops, so u need create a custom Map, for this, or i think it could run like `isValid.Select(x => Mapper.Map<ValidUser>(x));` try this;

Comment: If I do this it works  return db.spUserExists(GetShortname(), GetDomain(), 1).FirstOrDefault().UserExists; But how do I do it with mapping

Comment: With the above statement the return value is integer

Comment: so, i think when we use Mapper, benefit is return a obj, if u just return a type like this so need do like so `return isValid.Select(x => Mapper.Map<ValidUser>(x)).SingleOrDefault().UserExists;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the method UserValidate return type to be the List instead of Int32.